# Check for duplicate with same id before insert in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need update script where I must check before insert if there is the same row with the same code.

```
INSERT INTO Customers (UnicCode, CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
VALUES ('W5RTS', 'Cardinal', 'Tom B. Erichsen', 'Skagen 21', 'Stavanger', '4006', 'Norway');
```

How I can implement to this query select from `Customers` and if there is no such record to add new?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exists` is a very self-explanatory way to check for existence

```
insert into Customers
(
   UnicCode,
   CustomerName,
   ContactName,
   Address,
   City,
   PostalCode,
   Country
)
select   'W5RTS',
         'Cardinal',
         'Tom B. Erichsen',
         'Skagen 21',
         'Stavanger',
         '4006',
         'Norway'
where not exists
(
   select * from Customers where UnicCode = 'W5RTS'
);
```

Comment: I'll point out that this will cause the insert trigger on Customers to fire in all conditions. A good example of how a trigger can execute with zero rows in the inserted table.

Comment: @SMor I didn't want to change the statement structure of the OP, but yes, a useful addendum.

Answer (score 2):

You can just try `not exists` as shown below

```
if not exists (select 1 from Customers where UnicCode = 'W5RTS')
begin
   --Your insert logic/statements here
end
else
begin
  --Your update or other logic/statements here
end
```