# Does Insert with select guarantees non duplicate entry in postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, duplicates, atomic

I am trying to implement a logic where I need to check if there is any row with same value of a particular column already exists. If exists then it should not insert else it should insert.

Below is the query I am using, but need expert advice if this ensures guarantee of non duplicates.

insert into file_status (id, voucher_id, created_on, channel) select nextval('file_status_id_seq'),'TEST231123001',now(),'SFTP' where not exists (select * from file_status where voucher_id = 'TEST231123001')

Note: id is a auto increment sequence and is the primary key. Can't make voucher_id as primary key.

Here is the link where I found reference to this query.
[Check for duplicate with same id before insert in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62898100/check-for-duplicate-with-same-id-before-insert-in-sql-server)